# Dlookup barcode

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good morning,

I am a Pharmacist and am making a database to capture medications that are being made. I have a table called `"Medications"` and in that table are the primary key, `Barcode` and then a text field called `Drug`. I am obviously filling in both fields manually with a drug and its corresponding barcode, but I am trying to make it so that I have a form for input and in that form whoever is using it will scan the medication and then what is read in from the scanner will be converted to the actual drug name and not just the barcode number. I know that I will need to perform a `Dlookup` to perform this action but I cannot for the life of me seem to get it to work, any help or a place to start would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

My code so far

```
Private Sub MedicationUsed_AfterUpdate() 
MedicationUsed = DLookup("Drug", "Med Used", "[Barcode=]" & Barcode) 
End Sub
```

Comment: please post what you have tried.

Comment: `Private Sub MedicationUsed_AfterUpdate()

    MedicationUsed = DLookup("Drug", "Med Used", "[Barcode=]" & 
    Barcode)

    End Sub`

Comment: I think that you should spend 20 hours or so researching MS Access forms.
 Keywords: MS Access search form.  Here is an example [Microsoft Access Multi-Field Search Form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTiA_4Me0cI).

Comment: think you're using the wrong table name `Med Used` should this be `Medications` DLOOKUP is what,table,criteria.  Also, `me.medicationused=`

Comment: Scanners work similarly to a keyboard.  If a TextBox has focus and you scan a barcode the barcode will be entered into the TextBox.  The scanner will probably also enter a line return into the TextBox, which may helpful or problematic.  The can also program the scanner to send additional key code.  I recommend using a hand scanner to reduce user error and speed up data entry.  You will probably have to use the TextBox KeyUp event to process the scanners input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MedicationUsed = DLookup("Drug", "[Med Used]", "[Barcode]=" & Barcode)
```

or, more likely, as Barcode probably is a string:

```
MedicationUsed = DLookup("Drug", "[Med Used]", "[Barcode]='" & Barcode & "'")
```